# post Event for a lead getting incorrect type for WhatId

Tags: post

I am trying to post an Event for a lead in salesforce from an external system I am using the WhatId to link the event to the Lead and I am getting:

> MALFORMED_ID message: Related To ID: id value of incorrect type:
>   /00QM000000FL9TFMA1/ errorCode: MALFORMED_ID fields

Here is my body:

> { "WhatId"      : "/00QM000000FL9TFMA1/", "Description" : "this is a
>   API Test"  }

Comment: You are supposed to use whoId

Comment: I changed it to WhoId however I am still getting the same error MALFORMED_ID
message: Name ID: id value of incorrect type: /00QM000000FL9TFMA1/
errorCode: MALFORMED_ID

Comment: here is the body "WhoId"      : "/00QM000000FL9TFMA1/",
"Description" : "this is a API Test" 
}

Comment: remove /  from your id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use WhoId.

**WhoId:** The WhoId represents a human such as a lead or a contact. WhoIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhoId is equivalent to a contact’s ID or a lead’s ID. The label is Name ID.

**WhatId:** The WhatId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. WhatIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a related object. The label is Related To ID.

[Task and Event Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm)